# Add custom field within post text?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a custom field to a post within the actual post text, instead of doing it by entering it in the custom fields section under the post (via Screen Options -> Custom Fields), as I will be importing a lot of posts automatically all with different values for a custom field and therefore need to be able to set the custom field within the post text. How can this be done?

Comment: you have need to create metabox for post. for more details you can follow the below link - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Comment: How about [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode)?

Comment: Like GMarco24 writes - I would create a shortcode, that reads the custom field, and returns the data - That way you can use it in your post content.